# Hyperlinks stop working after using android's hardware/software back button:

Tags: cordova, hyperlink, hybrid, multiplatform

I've created a normal cordova app but there is something very strange about it. When I use android's hardware/software button every "a" hyperlink tag stops working. I've tested it on LG G4 and G5 and the same bug occurs. Here is the project's source - https://bitbucket.org/emanuilov/explorers And here is a built version - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2Pt0nJOnl49aXJlVWc4c0NqRG8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. It was that I was using the cordova google maps plugin, somehow it caused this bug. I've resolved it by using Google Maps Javascript API